# Gradle 2.2.3 taking too much time to build after update Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I have updated **Android Studio 2.3** today, after successfully updated, I am getting problem while syncing **Gradle with version 2.2.3**

Is there any issue with new version of **Android Studio 2.3?**

What should I do?

Comment: Use gradle plugin version "2.3.0" and gradle version "3.3".

Comment: I too updated to new android studio version and gradle sync is not working. But when I switch back to old android version gradle sync works well.

Comment: then what about new version?

Comment: @AkashPatel I done this thing, now working.

Comment: @PratikButani can you post your answer ?

Comment: @PratikButani glad to hear that... :)

Comment: @sur007 answer? :D thats why I asked question :)

Comment: @PratikButani I thought you said now working. So I asked if you have got the answer :)

Comment: Do you have an error in gradle messages?

Answer (score 1):

After updating **Android Studio 2.3**, you may have to update **gradle plugin** too as [described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle).

[image]

I just restarted AndroidStudio and done some process like [MAKE SURE THAT YOUR INTERNET HAVE ENOUGH SPEED]:

If you have set option for gradle as **"Use default gradle wrapper"** then it will ask as following, otherwise you have to select it.

[image]

Update with new gradle plugin:

[image]

It will work now for new plugins :) Enjoy with new gradle and Android Studio 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Exit as after run ./gradlew tasks from your project folder;

work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After completing all the above tasks, Now it shows another error as `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands`